# Creating a regular expression for parsing IUPAC organic compound names

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a parser in my free time that could parse out all the functional groups from the name of a organic compound. Side by side, I am also trying to make a display program which can read data from files to draw a visual representation of the compound on screen. Both are being done in python.

Right now the displayer is using a coordinate system to store the positions of atoms, which is why I am making the parser.

Here's the **code** so far:

```
import re
main_pattern = r"(.*)(meth|eth|prop|but|pent|hex|hept|oct|non|dec|isodec|dodec)-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-?(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(ane|ene|yne)(.*)"

prefix_patterns = [r"(?<!\d-\()(?<!-\()-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(methyl|ethyl|propyl|butyl|pentyl|hexyl|heptyl|octyl|nonyl|decyl)(?!\))",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(bromo|chloro|iodo|flouro)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(cyano)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(oxo|keto)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(alkoxy)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(hydroxy)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(formyl)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(carboxy)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(alkoxycabonyl)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(halocarbonyl)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(amino)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(carbamoyl)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(nitro)",
        r"-?([,?\d+,?]*)?-(di|tri|tetra|penta)?(suplho)"]

branch_pattern = r"-?(\d+,?)*?-\((.*?)\)"



compound_name = r"1-methyl-2-pentyl-3,64,7-trihexyl-5-oxo-12,6,7-triketo-23-(siugvuis)-68-(asdlkhdrjnkln)-42-(3,4-dimethylpentyl)pent-5,2,7-triyne"

prefixes = list(prefix_patterns)
print  compound_name
print '\n\n'
main=re.findall(main_pattern,compound_name)
print main
print '\n\n'
for x in prefix_patterns:
    prefixes = re.findall(x,main[0][0])
    print prefixes

branches = re.findall(branch_pattern,main[0][0])
print branches
```

In the example when the re matches the prefixes methyl in "1-methyl" , it also matches methyl from
-42-(3,4-dimethylpentyl). I looked up on negative lookahead/lookbehind. but couldn't get satisfying results.

Could you kindly point out the problem, and guide me to the answer?

Comment: What's the rule for when not to match `methyl`? Is it that it shouldn't match if there's another prefix?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to also show what the output should be.